# Is there any way to cache rtmp mp3 stream in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, caching, streaming, rtmp

I have made a mp3 flash player to play a rtmp mp3 stream and that is working fine.My problem is to cache that rtmp file in temporary file , so that the cache audio file could be played even when internet connection is not available .

So is it possible in flash AS3 to cache rtmp file ? 
if it is ..then suggest me how to do this ...

Thanks ,
nikesh

Comment: normaly you can not do this, since it is the essense of the RTMP ( Real Time ), so there is no need to cashe it. If you have made a Air based flash player ( ssuminig you targeting the desktops ), then you can record the sound and store it on user's mashine.

Comment: Actually I am making it for blackberry playbook ... I need to save the audio file for sometime (say for a day).So could you suggest me a way to save it other than recording ...

Comment: how to download rtmp stream ??

Comment: i mean simple file download. since you have some metadata comming from the stream, depending on it you can generate a link to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

This will likely be quite difficult to accomplish. I don't even know if it's possible, but my idea would be to use a `ByteArray` to *store* the data coming in and then ouput the data pre-download to *MP3*.

Hope that helps.